# Using Tkinter Themes in oop python

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, themes

I'm trying to use ttkthemes but for some reason when I import it i just get errors, It's telling me `AttributeError: module 'ttkthemes.themed_tk' has no attribute 'Tk'` so I tried changing Tk to ThemedTk but it still didn't work, thanks for any help in advance. 
Here's the original code

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk  
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkthemes import themed_tk as tk
class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage,Task):
            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        frame.winfo_toplevel().geometry("1024x720")
        frame.configure(bg='#333130')


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

class Task(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Change `from ttkthemes import themed_tk as tk` to `from ttkthemes.themed_tk import ThemedTk`, then change `class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk)` to `class SeaofBTCapp(ThemedTk)` and `tk.Tk.__init__(...)` to `ThemedTk.__init__(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you used `from ttkthemes import themed_tk as tk`.

When the next time you use `tk.Tk()`, it could be `themed_tk.Tk()`.Apparently, `Tk` class is in the module `tkinter`, not `themed_tk`.(Although you has used `import tkinter as tk`,it has been covered by `from ttkthemes import themed_tk as tk`.)

You could use `from ttkthemes import themed_tk as [another_name]` then do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You overwrote your `tk` wich represents the `tkinter` module with `ttkthemes.themed_tk`.

`tk.Tk` being the window of `tkinter` module you can't access it anymore